# Why is Facebook connect button on click throwing a JavaScript error?

Tags: javascript, facebook

We're having a really odd problem. Basically the Facebook Connect button we put up on our local testing site worked fine until yesterday, now whenever we click on it,
it seems to go the xd_receiver.htm page which just shows a blank page rather than the app login and throws an error on this javascript file:

```
 http://static.ak.connect.facebook.com/js/api_lib/v0.4/XdCommReceiver.js
```

The error is 403 forbidden, is this facebook blocking us? If so why could it be?

This is in our javascript tags:

```
<script src="http://static.ak.connect.facebook.com/js/api_lib/v0.4/FeatureLoader.js.php"
type="text/javascript"></script>

function OnRequestPermission() {
    var myPermissions = "publish_stream"; 
    FB.Connect.showPermissionDialog(myPermissions, function(perms) {
        window.location.reload()
        if (!perms) {
            // handles if the user rejects the request for permissions. 
            // This is a good place to log off from Facebook connect
        } else {
            // finish up here if the user has accepted permission request
        };
    });
}

FB.init("OUR_ID", "xd_receiver.htm");
```

This is in our HTML code:

```
<fb:login-button onlogin="OnRequestPermission();"></fb:login-button>
```

It all worked fine with the permissions etc. till yesterday and brought up the login page before but now just shows a blank page with 403 on the `XdCommReceiver.js` file. No changes were made to our app. It's stopping us from progressing with our company's app and any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I also get the 403 if I just copy the URL into a browser...but no idea why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The old featureloader.js SDK is deprecated - see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/oauth2-https-migration/ for more information - I'm surprised it was working as recently as last week - it was due to be shut off in October as far as I know